# How can I update a column's last but one record using Merge in sparksql

Tags: apache-spark, merge, apache-spark-sql

| ID | Invoice_id | next_invoice_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | IN-001 | IN-002 |
| 456 | IN-002 | REFUND-001 |
| 456 | REFUND-001 | IN-003 |
| 789 | IN-003 | IN-004 |
| 120 | IN-004 | IN-005 |
| 121 | IN-005 | null |

The moment when an new id is received, along with new invoice_id, then I want it to update as a new row like below and update the next_invoice_id last but one row and make the current received one as null. I want this to achieve using merge in spark sql.

| ID | Invoice_id | next_invoice_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | IN-001 | IN-002 |
| 456 | IN-002 | REFUND-001 |
| 456 | REFUND-001 | IN-003 |
| 789 | IN-003 | IN-004 |
| 120 | IN-004 | IN-005 |
| 121 | IN-005 | IN-006 |
| 122 | IN-006 | null |

```
merge table_name tn
using new_data nd
on tn.id = nd.id
and tn.invoice_id = nd.invoice_id
and tn.next_invoice_id = nd.next_invoice_id
```

Comment: What does the data in new_data look like?  I don't think that can be your full merge statement.

Comment: New data will have ID as 122 and invoice_id as IN-006, when this new data is received some how for IN-005, next invoice should be updated to IN-006 from null.
Yes, that cannot be my merge statement, but I want to show that I was trying that way.

Comment: I think you need to change your on clause to `and tn.next_invoice_id is null`.  Then for your on matched, set your next_invoice_id to whatever you want on that row, and insert your new one.  That's assuming you can only have 1 row with next_invoice_id null for any given invoice id.